# $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=8$， $x^3+y^3+z^3=1$ what is the Minimum value of $x^4+y^4+z^4$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math

Given that, for $x, y, z \in \mathbb R,\, $\begin{align}(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2&=8\\ x^3+y^3+z^3&=1, \end{align}

find the minimum value of $\;x^4+y^4+z^4$

Comment: are $$x,y,z$$ real numbers?

Comment: x,y,z are defined in R

Comment: How to know that the mentioned conditions are sufficient to find minimum value of $x^4+y^4+z^4$? I think we need to know that the value of $x+y+z$ to proof this question.

Comment: With Lagrange Multipliers method,Somebody has done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1^4+(-1)^4+1^4=3$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$, where $v^2$ can by negative, and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, $$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2=8$$ it's
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2-xy)=4$$ or
$$9u^2-9v^2=4.$$
In another hand, $$1=x^3+y^3+z^3=27u^3-27uv^2+3w^3=12u+3w^3,$$
which gives $v^2=u^2-\frac{4}{9}$ and $w^3=\frac{1}{3}-4u$.

Now, $(x-y)^2(x-z)^2(y-z)^2\geq0$ gives
$$3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6\geq0$$ or
$$3u^2\left(u^2-\frac{4}{9}\right)^2-4\left(u^2-\frac{4}{9}\right)^3-4u^3\left(\frac{1}{3}-4u\right)+6u\left(u^2-\frac{4}{9}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}-4u\right)-\left(\frac{1}{3}-4u\right)^2\geq0$$ or
$$(1-3u)(9u^2+3u+25)(27u^3+72u+7)\geq0$$ or
$$u_1\leq u\leq\frac{1}{3},$$
where $u_1$ is a real root of the equation $27u^3+72u+7=0$. $u_1=-0.096...$.

But $$x^4+y^4+z^4=81u^4-108u^2v^2+18v^4+12uw^3=$$
$$=3+\frac{1}{9}(1-3u)(27u^3+9u^2+51u+5)\geq3$$
for all $u_1\leq u\leq\frac{1}{3}$ and we are done!

Comment: But when it takes the equal sign，3v^2=xy+xz+yz=-1,that is unpossible

Comment: @lurk lurk $v^2$ can be negative. See third line of my proof.

Comment: you mean v is defined in C？@Michael Rozenberg

Comment: @lurk lurk I mean that $v^2$ can be negative real number. Say me please, why does this bother you?

Comment: Can I replace $v^2$ with v @Michael Rozenberg

Comment: @lurk lurk Yes, of course! But in this case $v$ can be negative and the expression like $\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2-xy)$ will be equal to $9u^2-9v$ and $x^3+y^2+z^3=27u^3-27uv+3w^3$.

Comment: If $$(a^5-a^3+3)(b^5-b^3+3)(c^5-c^3+3)\ge 3(a+b+c)^2 \quad a,b,c\in\mathbb R. $$ Prove that $a^5-a^3\ge a^2-1$.@Michael Rozenberg

Comment: @Peter Sheldrick $v^2$ is a real number. We work with $v^2$ only.